# Can't create a mesh from a loaded Three.js object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I used clara.io to export a model with four textures on it in the ThreeJS Object format. It results in a .json file. I am trying to load it and have it display correctly. If I do the following(taken directly from the clara.io exporting help), it loads and displays but without textures:

```
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load( "wsc3.json", function(obj){

        scene.add(obj);

        });
```

One thing that I have found, is, in reference to using a different kind of loader, it should be possible to convert the loaded object into a THREE.Mesh, get the textures, and then apply them to the mesh. I have a working example of this:

```
    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load("wsc3.js", function(geometry, materials){

        // get the materials loaded from the file
        var materialsFromFile = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);  

        // create our mesh with the loaded geometry and materials
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialsFromFile);

        scene.add(mesh);

    });
```

The problem with using the JSONLoader is that the model I am exporting has subparts, and when the .js file that the JSONLoader uses is exported, it loses the model hierarchy(I checked the .js file itself and none of the subparts are there. It is just a huge list of vertices). If I have a look at the .json file that clara.io exports, I can see the various subparts listed, so I would guess that I need to use this format.

I have looked around and seen that there is the suggestion to just create a new mesh from the obj that is generated by the ObjectLoader. Something like this:

```
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load( "wsc3.json", function(obj){

        // get the geometry from the obj
        var geometry = obj.geometry;
        // get the materials from the obj
        var materials = obj.materials;

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);

        scene.add(mesh);

    });
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Nothing displays. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Is there a format that Three.js will load, that not only brings the textures but the hierarchy as well?

Comment: `new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials )` expects a `THREE.Geometry` and a `THREE.Material`, not raw JSON data. Feed it proper objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that: var geometry = new THREE.Geometry(obj.geometry) as well as creating a new material as passing them into the THREE.Mesh constructor. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Alright. I found what I was doing wrong. I needed to export as a ThreeJS Scene. This brings over the hierarchy correctly and I can access the meshes by traversing the resulting object.